# Presenting Categorical by Continuous Interaction when Continuous Variable is Moderator

Tags: r, interaction, post-hoc

I am conducting an analysis in which I have an interaction between a categorical and continuous predictor on a continuous outcome variable. My question is how I should present these results to a reader with the caveat that it makes (conceptual) sense for the continuous variable to be the moderator, which precludes a common strategy used in which the association between the continuous predictor and outcome variables are plotted at each level of the categorical variable. For example:

[image: Example of interaction with categorical moderator]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I read the minitab blog but I did not see anything about the word "moderator".

Comment: Agreed, that was an unhelpful link. I replaced it with a more informative image.

Comment: The results of a model with an interaction cannot provide information as to which variable "modifies" the other. This graph would simultaneously suggest different effects of X1 by gender AND different effects of gender by x1.